# R: Identify non-identical elements in two vectors

Tags: r

I have two vectors and I want to know which indices in the vectors are not identical. I am not sure how to do this because `NA == NA` produces `NA` and `NA == 5` also produces `NA`. Can someone provide guidance?

```
# Create data with NA vs. 3
dat1 <- data.frame(foo = c(NA, 5, 9),
                  bar = c(3, 5, 9))

# Create data with NA vs. NA
dat2 <- data.frame(foo = c(NA, 5, 9),
                  bar = c(NA, 5, 9))

# Produces same result
dat1$foo == dat1$bar
dat2$foo == dat2$bar

identical((dat1$foo == dat1$bar), (dat2$foo == dat2$bar))
```

Comment: `ind = dat1$foo != dat1$bar;  which(is.na(ind) | ind)`

Comment: Brilliant in simplicity. Add as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

The below solution does not work when we have `NA`'s in both the columns. To handle that, we can declare a function :

```
dissimilar_index <- function(dat) {
    ind = with(dat, (foo == bar) | (is.na(foo) & is.na(bar)))  
    which(is.na(ind) | !ind)
}

dissimilar_index(dat1)
#[1] 1

dissimilar_index(dat2)
#integer(0)
```

To check the function creating a new dataframe `dat3`

```
dat3  = rbind(dat1, c(2, 3))
dat3
#  foo bar
#1  NA   3
#2   5   5
#3   9   9
#4   2   3

dissimilar_index(dat3)
#[1] 1 4
```

We can also use,

```
ind = !with(dat1, is.na(foo) == is.na(bar) & foo == bar)
which(!is.na(ind) & ind)
#[1] 1 

ind = !with(dat2, is.na(foo) == is.na(bar) & foo == bar)
which(!is.na(ind) & ind)
#integer(0)
```

Here, we check if both the columns are `NA`'s as well as both are equal.

**Original Answer**

We can get the indices of the columns which are not similar and add an additional check for `NA`s to get the indices using `which`.

```
ind = dat1$foo != dat1$bar
which(is.na(ind) | ind)

#[1] 1
```

Comment: Actually just realized it doesn't quite work for making the distinction between NA == NA and NA = 5. I'd want NA == NA to produce TRUE/not be included in the index.

Comment: I couldn't come up with anything better. My only possible rationalisation was `compNA <- function(x,y) union(which(is.na(x)!=is.na(y)), which(x!=y) )` then `compNA(dat3$foo, dat3$bar)`

Comment: @thelatemail yeah..At first even I thought that it must be some simple check. After spending 15-20 mins, this is the best I could come up with which is kind of sad. :|

Answer (score 2):

An approach using `sapply` and `identical`:

```
non_ident_ind <- function(df) {
    which(!sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) identical(df$foo[i], df$bar[i])))
}
```

Results:

```
non_ident_ind(dat1)
# [1] 1
non_ident_ind(dat2)
# integer(0)
```

---

Another approach using `apply`:

```
which(apply(dat1, 1, function(r) length(unique(r)) > 1))
# [1] 1
which(apply(dat2, 1, function(r) length(unique(r)) > 1))
# integer(0)
```